# Add where query to joins query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5 app.
In this app I got a query that get all the top five Ideas with the most likes. This query gives me Idea with zero likes too. I want to only get Ideas with at least one like. How can I change it?

```
Idea.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN Likes ON likes.likable_id = ideas.id").group("ideas.id").order("COUNT(likes.id) DESC").take(5)
```

Thankful for all help

**Update**

This seems to work

```
Idea.joins("INNER JOIN Likes ON likes.likable_id = ideas.id").group("ideas.id").order("COUNT(likes.id) DESC").take(5)
```

Comment: have you tried using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. This way you will only get the Ideas that have at least 1 like and avoid additional where clause

Comment: seems to work! Why does it work?

Comment: `INNER JOIN`  selects records that have matching values in both tables, wheres `LEFT OUTER JOIN` keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) instead of [LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp). This way you will only get the Ideas that have at least 1 like and avoid additional where clause.

```
Idea.joins(:likes).group("ideas.id").order("COUNT(likes.id) DESC").take(5)
```

Rails [joins](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins) method does `INNER JOIN` by default

> INNER JOIN selects records that have matching values in both tables,
>   wheres LEFT OUTER JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table
>   (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The
>   result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.